# Postgres: fulltext filter on result row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using [jTable](http://www.jtable.org/) to present a table of say, customers. This table supports filtering on various criteria, sorting the results, and paging.

All of this is reflected in the Postgres query to fetch the data:

```
SELECT
  ...some columns...
FROM
  ...some table...
WHERE
  ...filter conditions...
ORDER BY
  ...sort order...
OFFSET offset LIMIT limit;
```

Now the table should be able to do a "fulltext" search, meaning: if the search term is not found as a substring in any of the columns of the result row, this row is not admitted.

My first approach was to render each row into JSON (as jTable requires it) and then do a `String.contains()`, but this does not work well with the rest of the filtering/sorting/pagination.

What I want is a way to check if the term is contained in the query result row, and I want this to be part of the query. I do not want to explicitly check each of the columns: `... AND (col1 LIKE '%term%' OR col2 LIKE '%term%' OR ...`.

Is there a way to do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate all the columns together into a single string and then do the search:

```
SELECT ...some columns...
FROM (SELECT ...some columns...,
             concat_ws(, '|', ...some columns...) as tosearch
      FROM ...some table...
      WHERE ...filter conditions...
      ORDER BY...sort order...
      OFFSET offset LIMIT limit
     ) t
WHERE tosearch like '%searchterm%';
```

As a note:  `concat_ws()` ignores `NULL`s, so you don't have to worry about a `NULL` search string.

Comment: This is an okay approach I guess, thanks. I'd still prefer not having to explicitly concat those columns (it means writing their names twice and can get out of sync as the query evolves), but it's good enough.